# What's the 2N3904 / 2N3906 FET equivalent?

Tags: mosfet, bjt, jfet

Is there a generic low-power switching FET that's multiply sourced, generally readily available, most simulators already have models for, etc.?

I'm not looking for FETs that have similar electrical characteristics to the 3904/3906; I'm looking for FETs that have similar ubiquity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2N3819 and 2N3820 JFETs, BSS84 and BSS123 MOSFETs. They are rather old, but are readily available.